# Please help that I can @font-face for only web not mobile

Tags: conditional-statements, font-face, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have been using @font-face for only web not mobile.

below code was work!! before update ie10...

[image]

font.css -> There is media-query. 
iefont.css -> There is no media-query.

and I found that ie10 is not supported conditionl comment. (and ie11 too..)
and Also ie is not supported @font-face in media query...

In my case I have to use @font-face only web NOT mobile. 
so I'm searching Various way..

for example..

if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';}

or

if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')() && window.innerWidth >= 980) {
          var link  = document.createElement('link');
          link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
          link.href = 'css/fonts.min.css';
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
       }

-> these codes works but... only ie10 and it can not read @font-face but it can read just css.

and so on...(just like css)

I thought I can solve it by using css! but... maybe it will never solve by using css..

Anyone solve it? How can you solve it?

Please Help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can target ie mobile using conditional comments...the example below is how to target everything but ie mobile:

```
<![if !IEMobile]> 
<style> put your @font-face here </style>
<![endif]>
```

if you still have to target ie10, you can use conditional compilation for targeting, which is almost exactly like conditional comments. you can see a working demo here: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ua/browsers/ie/ie10-detection-via-cc.html

Comment: First, Thank you for your answer!! 
But, as I know, conditional comment is not working anymore.. 
and If it works, in my case I have to use font-face in only web browser(mac, window pc and so on). I don't need to use font-face for mobile page(ex. iphone,galaxy and so on).

Comment: And then I have to separate the css from html. 
I don't have to target ie10 web browser(pc), I mean I have to target ie10 and higher version(ex.ie11).

Comment: because, new higher version(pc browser)dropped conditional comment and dose not support font-face within media query. 
If you have any information about this problems, please share with me. 
Thank you!

Comment: so use conditional compilation to target ie10 +

Comment: Sorry for that I confused conditional comment with conditional compilation and Thank you for huge tip!! I'll try to solve this by using it. however.. I don't know about javascript well...

Comment: Could you help me more? If To help me more is not easy, just give tip more. I'll study it!